# Can I keep my packages in project/packages?

Tags: packages

I have a project directory `project` with file `project/main.tex`, a directory `project/chapters` and lots of other stuff. I also have a couple of packages for this project.

Is it possible to keep them in a subdirectory `project/packages`?

If I keep them directly in `project`, they will clutter my project directory. If I keep them in `$TEXMFHOME`, I cannot have them under version control together with my project.

I also tried to keep them in `project/packages` and to symlink them to `TEXMFHOME`, which does not seem to work.

Do you have any suggestions? In case it is important, I use Linux, and usually I compile with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: It is *not* standard procedure to store packages in the project directory (or its subdirectories).  Rather, your LaTeX installation maintains its own package directory where packages should be located and maintained. For "local" packages, that are not available through your LaTeX distribution, one typically maintains a secondary `localtexmf` directory tree for such packages, using the facilities of your installation to make sure it is searched during compilations.

Comment: `localtexmf` is the better option...

Comment: build a small texmf-tree in say project/texmf and then attach this tree with `tlmgr conf auxtrees add` (assuming a current texlive). See https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#conf

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! I'd be willing to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a small texmf-tree in say `project/texmf` and then attach this tree with

```
   tlmgr conf auxtrees add path/to/project/texmf
```

This assumes a current texlive. See also https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#conf.